# Centering a background image, using CSS and div

Tags: css

I want to center a background image. There is div used, this is the CSS style:

```
.background-cover {
    position: absolute;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    top: 34px;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

I dont have `background-image`, the img in the `div` like:-

`<div><img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/small-n-flat/24/user-alt-16.png"></div>`

The above CSS tiles all over and does center it, but half the image is not seen, it just kind of moves up. What I want to do is center the image. Could I adopt the image to view even on a 21" screen?

Comment: Can we have your code in fiddle.

Comment: you can add background-position: center center

Comment: can you see my edit of post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check the code below and [link here](http://jsfiddle.net/rjgbgh44/)

```
.bgImage{
    background-image: url('https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/small-n-flat/24/user-alt-16.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-size: contain;
}
```

Comment: i dont have `background-image`, the img in the `div` like:-
`<div><img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/small-n-flat/24/user-alt-16.png"></div>`

Comment: if the images width like 1300px its not work can you test ?

Comment: if the image will big, it will wraps into full width of the div

Comment: you are add background-image but i dont have in class background-image, its in div images like `<div><img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/small-n-flat/24/user-alt-16.png"></d‌​iv>`

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

`<div class="background-cover"/>`

```
.background.cover{
    background-image: url('https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/small-n-flat/24/user-alt-16.png');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
}
```

If it doesn't work you can also try:

`background-position: 0 100px;/*use a pixel value that will center it*/` Or I think you can use 50% if you have set your body `min-height` to `100%`.

```
.background.cover{
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-image: url('https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/small-n-flat/24/user-alt-16.png');
    color:#FFF;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    min-height:100%;
}
```

Comment: i dont have background-image, the img in the div like:- <div><img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/small-n-flat/24/user-alt-16.png"></d‌​iv>

Comment: just forget about the image inside, I've updated the answer specifying the html code too